# how to convert OST file PST file in java?

Tags: java

I have one .ost File Offline Outlook Data File, I want to extract data inside that file like emails, attachments etc.

For that i did not get any direct parser for ost file so i can extract data inside that. I have code to extract data from .pst file.

So according to my requirement i want to convert .ost file to .pst file in java. Help from anyone will be appreciated .

I am trying following code but its giving me exception , i am not getting any solution for this .

```
package com.common;

import com.aspose.email.FileFormat;
import com.aspose.email.PersonalStorage;

public class ParseOST {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            PersonalStorage ost = PersonalStorage.fromFile("F:/OSTFiles/OTest.ost");
            ost.saveAs("F:/OSTFiles/DuplicateOTest.pst", FileFormat.Pst);
            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Exception :

```
FormatNotSupportedException: The file is not in PST format
    [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@86be70a
       at com.aspose.email.akv.c(SourceFile:670)
       at com.aspose.email.afi.j(SourceFile:1629)
       at com.aspose.email.afi.b(SourceFile:1280)
       at com.aspose.email.afi.<init>(SourceFile:162)
       at com.aspose.email.yy.<init>(SourceFile:43)
       at com.aspose.email.aku.<init>(SourceFile:123)
       at com.aspose.email.PersonalStorage.a(SourceFile:299)
       at com.aspose.email.PersonalStorage.fromFile(SourceFile:242)
       at com.aspose.email.PersonalStorage.fromFile(SourceFile:215)
       at com.common.ParseOST.main(ParseOST.java:12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remark: the error says "The file is not in PST format", it seems that it is not problem with code

if you want to use this, commercial product:
http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/emailjava/Load+and+Convert+Outlook+Offline+Folder+File+%28OST%29

```
PersonalStorage ost = PersonalStorage.FromFile("input.ost"))
ost.SaveAs("output.pst", FileFormat.Pst);
```

Or use an open source library:

To deal with PST file: 
https://code.google.com/p/java-libpst/

this deals also with OST file.

Some example: http://contactvarunagarwal.blogspot.fr/2014/05/i-was-searching-many-times-how-to-read.html

Hope it helps

Comment: I Want to access that file from file Directory means from some other drive .

Comment: I dont understand. Error seems to be related for file format, not to the path.

Comment: PersonalStorage ost = PersonalStorage.fromFile("F:/OSTFiles/OTest.ost");

                ost.saveAs("F:/OSTFiles/DuplicateOTest.pst", FileFormat.Pst);   this is the code i am writing I want to convert OST to PST so I have to give file path of ost file .

Comment: Thanks   @ guillaume girod-vitouchkina  It worked for me , My File was corrupted so it was giving exception .